# Can I link to my own app to give better context of what my problem is?

Tags: discussion

I've just opened this post: [Is it worthwhile to offer a "recover your status" functionality for a paid version in phone app?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/135298/is-it-worthwhile-to-offer-a-recover-your-status-functionality-for-a-paid-versi)

I think maybe people would find it easier it they can check what exactly am I talking about that would be needed to be recovered, even if I were to explain it in a written way I think it may be quite messy.

But on the other hand, I perfectly understand this could be considered as spam, so I've refrained from doing that by now.

Would such a behavior be allowed?

Answer (score 2):

In order to assist you in finding a solution, as well as provide educational value to the community, the current state of your application should be preserved as a moment in time via screenshots, video/GIFs, or reproduced as wireframes.

Your app may change or become inaccessible in the future, but if you capture the relevant parts and include them with your question, the question will still be able to retain its value.

Answer (score 1):

There have been people in the past who have used this method of posting a link to their own work in a way that would be considered spam.

I think there are some steps that can be taken to avoid this potential conflict of interest by:

1. Stating this very clearly right at the beginning of the question
2. Putting images instead of links to illustrate the point you want to make in the question

But I believe a safer way would be just to use a wireframe or mockup to illustrate the same question without having to reference the site directly where possible.